# i don't know why this table view code crashes

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

hello i'm studying iOS programming

i created a project, which is an empty application

and i created table view controller without xib file.

and i inserted follow code in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

```
TableViewController *tvc = [[TableViewController alloc] init];
[self.window addSubView:tvc.view];
[tvc release];
```

this code was crashed when i scrolled down. why is that?

when i comment this code

```
[tvc release];
```

program doesn't crash.

i didn't write dealloc in AppDelegate file.

why is that??

i think i created table view controller with alloc

so retain count is 1.

and add sub view to window and table view controller retain count is 2.

so i release table view controller

but it crash when i scrolled down.

i don't know why..

help me please

Comment: It is custom to set UIWindow's main view as window.rootViewController; not as a subview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple, adding `tvc.view` as a subview of the window causes `tvc.view` to be retained but does not retain `tvc` itself.  In essence, your `TableViewController` instance becomes invalid as soon as you call `release` on it.  The app crashes when you scroll presumably because the `TableViewController` instance is configured as a delegate or datasource for a `UITableView` or `UIScrollView` or any other thing associated with `tvc.view`.

Also note that the way you are displaying the view is not the recommended way to go about it.  Really you should be calling `presentModalViewController:` or `pushViewController:` and passing the `TableViewController` instance.  This will cause the `TableViewController` to be retained until it is dismissed/popped, making it safe for you to call `release` as in your example code.

Or, since you are doing this setup manually as part of `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`, you can also set `window.rootViewController` directly, though again that's not really recommended.  XCode allows you to specify the app's default/root view controller and will automatically set it up for you when the app launches.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you have just added the view alone. So the view alone will be retained. The viewcontroller will be released. But the viewcontroller needs to be the datasource and delegate for the tableview. Since it has been deallocated, that datasource will not have any valid reference and so it crashes.